# Как установить cookie в NanoHTTPD.Response?

Tags: java, cookie, nanohttpd

Какие методы и классы используются для этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде бы ничего сложного:

```
@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    session.getCookies().set(new Cookie("uid", "123"));
    return newFixedLengthResponse("<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1></body></html>\n");
}
```